# let indexing return a matrix instead of a vector in julia

Tags: matrix, julia

When you index a matrix in Julia, and your selection is a single column or row the result will be represented as a vector. similarly, when you index a single point you get the value of that point, not a 1x1 matrix.

However, for my use case I want my answer to be a matrix as well, because the orientation of the vector has meaning, that I don't want to lose.

So given the following example matrix:

```
julia> A = [1 2; 3 4]
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2
 3  4
```

I get:

```
julia> A[:, 1]
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 3

julia> A[1, :]
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2

julia> A[1, 1]
 1
```

but I want:

```
julia> A[:, 1]
2×1 Matrix{Int64}:
 1
 3

julia> A[1, :]
1×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1 2

julia> A[1, 1]
1×1 Matrix{Int64}:
 1
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Right now I do something like:

```
function getindex_asmatrix(A::Matrix, i, j)
    # If i & j are Integers convert point to 1x1 Matrix
    # If only j == Integer make a nx1 Matrix
    # If only i == Integer make a 1xm Matrix
    # else do A[i, j]
end
```

But I feel there might be an more elegant solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use `1:1` (range) instead of `1`, e.g.:

```
julia> A[:, 1:1]
2×1 Matrix{Int64}:
 1
 3

julia> A[1:1, :]
1×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2

julia> A[1:1, 1:1]
1×1 Matrix{Int64}:
 1
```

You could also use `[1]` instead, but it will allocate, while `1:1` does not allocate.